# SQLAlchemy ORM: proxy attribute pointing to the first element of a relation?

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy

Starting from the [many-to-many relationship example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) from the SQLAlchemy documentation, I want to add an attribute `first_child` that will return the first child of `children` defined by the relationship. The `first_child` attribute needs to be useable in an [`association_proxy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy.association_proxy) attribute definition such as `first_child_id` below.

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('left_id', Integer, ForeignKey('left.id')),
    Column('right_id', Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'))
)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", secondary=association_table)
    first_child = ???
    first_child_id = association_proxy('first_child', 'id')

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

I'm thinking I need a to declare `first_child` as either a [`hybrid_property` or a `column_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html), but I don't know how to return the first element.

In addition to `first_child`, I also need `last_child` and an associated `last_child_id` attribute.

I'm using SQLAlchemy with a MySQL database.

Comment: But what's wrong with using `children.first()`?

Comment: @IgorHatarist Have you even tried that? Fails with `'RelationshipProperty' object has no attribute 'first'`

Comment: Try `children[0]` to get the first child. But this does not completely answer your question. May I ask why do you need to keep track of first and last child? How is the ordering of children performed?

Comment: @BrechtMachiels I'm sorry, of course it's `children[0]`.

Comment: @van yes, `children[0]` will work only for instances. In my case, children are events with a start/end time. I want to create `start_time` and `end_time` attributes on the parent that get the value from the first and last child respectively.

Comment: In this case, you can simply make a  `children` relationship [ordered](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.order_by) and do not need to add *first* and *last* pointers, which would be redundant.

Comment: @van You mean to use `parent.children[0].start_time` where I need it? I already have specified `order_by` for children, but I'd really like to have the proxy attributes if that's possible.

Comment: Just define a `one-to-one` relationship in this case. Again, you would not need to have additional columns on the `Parent` table (unless you really want to).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `association_proxy` is that you cannot use it on `hybrid_properties` (or at least not in a direct manner).

A simple solution might be to use a `property` decorator, which would be evaluated on an already-loaded instance:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", secondary=association_table)

    @property
    def first_child(self):
        return children[0]
```

However, you will not be able to use it on queries and it is a "read only" property. More information on [SQLAlchemy plain-descriptor](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-a-plain-descriptor).

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to have *minimum start_time* and *maximum end_time*, then I would use `column_property` just for these columns:

```
association_table = Table(
    'association', Base.metadata,
    Column('left_id', Integer, ForeignKey('left.id')),
    Column('right_id', Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'))
)


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    start_time = Column(DateTime)
    end_time = Column(DateTime)


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship(
        "Child",
        secondary=association_table,
        backref="parents",
    )

    min_start_time = column_property(
        select([Child.start_time.label("min_start_time")])
        .where(Child.id == association_table.c.right_id)
        .where(id == association_table.c.left_id)
        .order_by(Child.start_time.asc())
        .limit(1)
    )

    max_end_time = column_property(
        select([Child.end_time.label("max_end_time")])
        .where(Child.id == association_table.c.right_id)
        .where(id == association_table.c.left_id)
        .order_by(Child.end_time.desc())
        .limit(1)
        .as_scalar()
    )
```

But if you need more than one such special column from the relationship, probably it would be more efficient to use `hybrid_property`.

Comment: This will work, but I'm disappointed that this requires redefining the parent-child relationship. Isn't it possible to make use of the existing `children` attribute? Also, I need attributes that point to the first and last children.